# Split a string but keep the delimiter in the same resulting substring in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string containing URLs:

`string = https://www.link1.net/abc/cik?xai=En8MmT__aF_nQm-F48&amp;sig=Cg0A7_5AE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;;ccurl=https://aax-us.link-two.com/x/c/Qoj_sZnkA%2526adurl%253Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.link-three.mu%252F`

I want to extract all of them to have a result like this:

`['https://www.link1.net/abc/cik?xai=En8MmT__aF_nQm-F48&amp;sig=Cg0A7_5AE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;;ccurl=','https://aax-us.link-two.com/x/c/Qoj_sZnkA%2526adurl%253D','http%253A%252F%252Fwww.link-three.mu%252F']`

I am trying:

```
urls = [x for x in re.split('(http[s]?)', string) if x]
print urls
```

And the result is:

`['https', '://www.link1.net/abc/cik?xai=En8MmT__aF_nQm-
F48&amp;sig=Cg0A7_5AE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;;ccurl=', 'https', '://aax-us.link-two.com/x/c/Qoj_sZnkA%2526adurl%253D', 'http', '%253A%252F%252Fwww.link-three.mu%252F']`

How can I get the the complete URL together given that it can start with 'http' or 'https'?

Any ideas please?

Comment: Use a lookahead `(?=http)`. Also, no need to put `s` in a set `[s]` as it's interpreted literally by default (it doesn't have special meaning alone). Also, no need to check for `s` since `http` is all you really need to look for (think about it, who cares if there's an `s` at the end of `http` if `http` exists - it already satisfies your first requirement).

Comment: What is or are the URLs that you try to match? Where do they end? Do you consider the one starting with `http%253a` a valid URL?

Comment: This is a single url `https://aax-us.link-two.com/x/c/Qoj_sZnkA%2526adurl%253Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.link-three.mu%252F`

Comment: Yes, you're right, http is all I really need. So the whole string comes from a URL redirection scheme in which I need to extract all the URLs in the chain. Now, I am decoding the urls before splitting them so all the urls are valid in the form of http://.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `re`, you can handle this problem as follows:

```
['http' + x for x in filter(lambda x: x, string.split('http'))]
```

The result will be:

```
['https://www.link1.net/abc/cik?xai=En8MmT__aF_nQm-
F48&amp;sig=Cg0A7_5AE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;;ccurl=', 'https://aax-us.link-
two.com/x/c/Qoj_sZnkA%2526adurl%253D', 'http%253A%252F%252Fwww.link-
three.mu%252F']
```

Comment: I believe string methods are typically faster than `re`, so this is a better solution than the others presented so far.

Comment: use `filter(None, string.split('http'))`, it's even cleaner. Otherwise good alternative to regex

Comment: Yes, faster indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You could use your result and join 2 consecutive matches, that would work.

```
urls = [urls[i]+urls[i+1] for i in range(0,len(urls),2)]
```

But better use `findall` with a lookahead on `https?` or end of string:

```
import re

string = "https://www.link1.net/abc/cik?xai=En8MmT__aF_nQm-F48&amp;sig=Cg0A7_5AE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;;ccurl=https://aax-us.link-two.com/x/c/Qoj_sZnkA%2526adurl%253Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.link-three.mu%252F"

print(re.findall("https?.*?(?=https?|$)",string))
```

result:

```
['https://www.link1.net/abc/cik?xai=En8MmT__aF_nQm-F48&amp;sig=Cg0A7_5AE&amp;urlfix=1&amp;;ccurl=',
 'https://aax-us.link-two.com/x/c/Qoj_sZnkA%2526adurl%253D', 
 'http%253A%252F%252Fwww.link-three.mu%252F']
```

as noted in comments, since you cannot add `:` to the delimiter, you have no way of being sure of the URL delimitation (if an URL contains `http` inside the address you're toast)

Comment: Tested and working well but the string methods worked faster in my large scale project. I used this for another issue tho.